# Cannot exec /bin/false: no such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, osx

I'm trying to open [GNU Screen](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/GNU_Screen) with the following command on my Mac OS:

```
host:~ user$ screen
```

The screen terminal opens but quickly dies with the error message:

> Cannot exec /bin/false: no such file or directory

My terminal is configured to open `bash` shell on startup. I've tried setting the terminal shell to `sh`, it gives the same error.

However, when I execute `screen` command as `sudo`, then the command succeeds.

How do I resolve it for the normal user?

Comment: Search for `/bin/false` in your rc-files (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` etc.) Also check your `.screenrc`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look in your shell initialisation scripts for `bash`, or the `screen` config file, and see if there's anywhere `false` is being used with the explicit path `/bin/false`.

On macOS, the `false` utility is located in `/usr/bin`, not in `/bin`.

Failing that, see if your login shell for some odd reason is set to `/bin/false`, either by inspecting `/etc/passwd` or looking at the "Advanced Options" in the "User & Groups" section of the System Preferences (you get these by right-clicking on your user in the list of user accounts, and you may change the shell here too).  Someone may have *unthinkingly* followed [a tutorial/HOWTO](https://gist.github.com/joaopizani/5201352) which sets up a user with `/bin/false` as their default shell.

When you run `screen` with `sudo` you use `root`'s shell/screen init files. This is why that works.

Comment: Sorry, pressing enter accidentally posted the incomplete comment.

I checked the following files:
/etc/passwd and ~/.screenrc.

However, it seems my shell was setup with /bin/false as default shell. When I did an "echo $SHELL" it gave "/bin/false". Doing an "export SHELL=/bin/bash" fixed the issue. :)

Comment: @sultan.of.swing Good! You should *change* your default shell in the System Preferences. Also, if this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

Go to preferences on Terminal and then go to general,then under 'Shell open with' select Command and type bash -l

Comment: Please explain **what** this does and **how** it solves the problem.

Comment: is that "bash -<Capital Eye>" or "bash-<Uncial Ell>" ?

Comment: best answer this is